# How do you iterate through the keys/members in a JSON object using Yojson?

Tags: json, key, ocaml

The only examples I can see so far about processing json objects involve knowing the key beforehand, but how would I be able to go through the keys/members and process their values individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've created a `json` instance, perhaps by reading from a file using `Yojson.Basic.from_channel (open_in filename)` or from a string using `Yojson.Basic.from_string string`, you could then convert it to an association list using `Yojson.Basic.Util.to_assoc` and recursively iterate over it like this:

```
open Yojson.Basic

let iter js =
  let rec f (nm,j) =
    Printf.printf "\"%s\": " nm;
    match j with
    | `Assoc a ->
       Printf.printf "assoc\n";
       List.iter f a
    | `Bool b ->
       Printf.printf "bool: %b\n" b
    | `Float f ->
       Printf.printf "float: %f\n" f
    | `Int i ->
       Printf.printf "int: %d\n" i
    | `List jl ->
       Printf.printf "list: [";
       List.iter (List.iter f) (List.map Util.to_assoc jl);
       Printf.printf "]\n"
    | `Null ->
       Printf.printf "null\n"
    | `String s ->
       Printf.printf "string: \"%s\"\n" s in
  List.iter f (Util.to_assoc js)
```

This `iter` function first converts its `js` argument to an association list and then iterates over it using function `f`. The `f` function takes a tuple argument of a string and a `json` type. For the sake of this example it prints the string, then matches the `json` type and acts on it accordingly. Note how `f` handles the values for the `` `Assoc `` and `` `List `` variants recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Yojson was designed to serve as the runtime for [atdgen](https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/). Atdgen saves users a lot of time by translating JSON data into data of your OCaml types and vice-versa.

The [solution for JSON objects representing association lists](https://mjambon.github.io/atdgen-doc/atdgen#association-lists) is the following (sample source file `assoc.atd`):

```
type t = (string * foo) list <json repr="object">

type foo = {
  x: int;
  y: int;
}
```

Sample data of type `t` in JSON format:

```
{
  "p1": { "x": 1, "y": 2 },
  "p2": { "x": 14, "y": 0 },
  "q": { "x": 9, "y": -1 }
}
```

The generated interface for this example is:

```
(* This is file assoc_j.mli derived from assoc.atd.
   It provides the serializers and deserializers for JSON.
   Other files are generated for other purposes,
   including assoc_t.mli which contains only the OCaml
   type definitions.
 *)

type foo = Assoc_t.foo = { x: int; y: int }

type t = Assoc_t.t

val write_foo :
  Bi_outbuf.t -> foo -> unit
  (** Output a JSON value of type {!foo}. *)

val string_of_foo :
  ?len:int -> foo -> string
  (** Serialize a value of type {!foo}
      into a JSON string.
      @param len specifies the initial length
                 of the buffer used internally.
                 Default: 1024. *)

val read_foo :
  Yojson.Safe.lexer_state -> Lexing.lexbuf -> foo
  (** Input JSON data of type {!foo}. *)

val foo_of_string :
  string -> foo
  (** Deserialize JSON data of type {!foo}. *)

val write_t :
  Bi_outbuf.t -> t -> unit
  (** Output a JSON value of type {!t}. *)

val string_of_t :
  ?len:int -> t -> string
  (** Serialize a value of type {!t}
      into a JSON string.
      @param len specifies the initial length
                 of the buffer used internally.
                 Default: 1024. *)

val read_t :
  Yojson.Safe.lexer_state -> Lexing.lexbuf -> t
  (** Input JSON data of type {!t}. *)

val t_of_string :
  string -> t
  (** Deserialize JSON data of type {!t}. *)
```